# Is there a way to deploy Libgdx Desktop application with Android Studio (An IntelliJ Idea based IDE)

Tags: java, deployment, intellij-idea, android-studio, libgdx

I have read [this article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-windowslinuxmac-os-x) about deploying libgdx application on linux, windows and macs.

However, it only describes how to export using eclipse. I am currently using Android Studio and it deploys android *.apk files very nicely. And I intend to keep using this. However, I had not figured out a way to deploy the desktop version of the project.

Can anyone tell me how to deploy a Libgdx Desktop application with Android Studio (or Intellij Idea because they are pretty much the same).

Comment: So are you successful? I can run the desktop app fine but does not know how to deploy. Have you tried others like iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, tell Gradle to build a jar for you. [Here's how.](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html)

In Android Studio you can start the Gradle tasks from the GUI on the right side. Anyways, I recommend you to learn first without an IDE.

Comment: Yes, I like your link, but I still don't understand how to do it exactly. Where do i type gradle uploadArchives?

Comment: Well, gradle is a command-line tool, and you specify the tasks on the command-line, but in Android Studio you can start them from the GUI on the right side. Anyway, I recommend to learn first without an IDE. Here's a simple tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

Comment: And here is a libgdx-specific tutorial: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline

Answer (score 10):

you can simply click on Gradle panel in the right, select :desktop, press the Execute Gradle Task, type dist and press enter, that's it.

Jar is located in /desktop/build/libs.

lbalazscs gave you a more detailed answer, so i recommend you doing what he said.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Android Studio to run the desktop version by setting up a new run configuration. Then you can run the desktop version just like you would the Android version.

Follow this link: [Configuring a libGDX project to run as a desktop application in Android Studio](https://words.strivinglife.com/post/configuring-a-libgdx-project-to-run-as-a-desktop-application-in-android-studio/).

Comment: He is asking how to create a runnable JAR file, not running app in Android Studio.

Comment: This was the answer to the question I asked Google, even if it isn't the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

In GUI we can do it.

Menu: Run -> Edit Configurations -> Add New Gradle Configurations

Gradle project: choose main Gradle project

Taske : gradlew desktop:dist

Then Run this configuration.

From this link:
[exporting-a-libgdx-game-as-executable-jar-from-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302235/exporting-a-libgdx-game-as-executable-jar-from-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of deploying on windows is to make a jar using gradle with the command `gradlew desktop:dist` in terminal.  A similar command can be used on Linux as well.