# Exporting A Libgdx Game as Executable Jar from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, executable-jar

Okay so I made a game using Libgdx and I intended it to be a android app(which is why i use android studio) but I want to let my friend without android phones try it out. The project is already setup for both desktop and android so is there any way to export this as a executable jar file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type the command below in the terminal. Remember that you have to be in your LibGDX root directory, before issuing this command.

```
gradlew desktop:dist
```

More at: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-the-desktop

Comment: um I don't really understand the gradlew stuff, where do I type this?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out that its the windows command line and that I need to cd to the project directory which has the build.gradle stuff and then use these commands

Comment: (For IntelliJ) You can open the "Gradle" panel at the right of theIDE and expand ":desktop", "other" and then double click on ":desktop:dist"

Answer (score 4):

You have to type

```
gradlew desktop:dist
```

command in **Terminal in Android Studio**. Then you should have an executable jar file in your project directory/desktop/build/libs.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be the terminal in AS. You can use any terminal to do this. Make sure the current working directory is the project root since `gradlew` is located there

Comment: This is a MUCH better answer than the one above since the jar file is built in a weird location, I couldn't see where it was an assumed it was failed. Thanks.